# Convert json byte Array image to c# list

Tags: asp.net, json, image, web-services, arrays

JSON string:

```
 { "Result": 
           [
                { "food_photo":255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1.....4,255,217],
                  "qty":"12",
                  "time":"23",
                  "cost":null
                }
           ]
   }
```

My question: how to convert `food_photo` into a list?

FYI: I use `public byte[] food_photo` in my class but it shows null when I execute my list.

Answer (score 1):

Try deserialize food_photo into string and use string.split method

```
string deserializedFoodPhoto = "255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,4,255,217";
var photoInList = deserializedFoodPhoto.Split(',').Select(i => byte.Parse(i)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable rply!but i cant get deserialized image array in above json

Comment: AFAIK for (de)serialization of JSON objects you can use System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer or maybe better System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer because your json object is quite deep.